# How Is possible to combine two NFT into one?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, nft, ethereum-wallet-dapp

For example, I have two **NFTs** and I want to combine them, my question is to know if is possible and which is the best way to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Answer (score 2):

Since blockchain data is immutable by default, you can not change a NFT already created, although if your metadata is hosted in somewhere you could change the data there where your NFT is pointing to.

I don't know what you want by "combine", but you may get the same result if you create a new NFT with both data 'combined', but in order to mint this new NFT the person should send those 2 NFT to a burn address. In that case you would have a combined NFT and the two previous NFT wouldn't have any usage anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for! ;)

> Mint a new NFT, burn the NFT's combined to make it. That's the basics for what is being done.

Depending on how your `metadata` is structured, this could be something super easy to do or on the contrary, something that can be very hard to do. It's even possible to split '***NFT combinations***' into their constructive parts, but it depends on your contract and the new metadata.

As a further explanation of why the metadata is so important in this,  say every part of the original NFTs have **attributes** with an `ID`, and it would be fairly easy to connect that with ID's of the new NFT.

However, if you don't have that `stored` or don't have a table connecting attribute names to IDs you may have to randomly generate the new images in the outside program you are using to call **mint functions**.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but based on my understanding you need to write a function which burns the two nfts and then mints the new replacement